# How to automatically limit the number of rows in a database?

Tags: mysql, delete-row, sql-delete, sql-limit

I have the following table

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| userid    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| logintime | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| loginIP   | int(4) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I insert a new row in this table every time a user logs in, which contains  their login time, IP address etc...

Now I want to limit the number of rows to only 10 per user! i.e. if there's 10 rows for userid 5, already and I'm inserting a new one, I need to delete the oldest one of them before the insert.

is there a way to write a SQL statement that `DELETE`s all entries of a userid, except for the recent 10 ones. I know how to use `LIMIT` for a `SELECT`, but I cannot see how I can implement the LIMIT in a `DELETE`.

Comment: Seems like a perfect case for using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

Comment: @Riki Lyng SQL does not provides this feature directly. As bfavaretto said, you may add a trigger that deletes or restricts insertion to your table. Other way, is to modify your code that is calling the MySQL database to limit insertions

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines should work:

```
DELETE FROM
  table 
WHERE
 userID = xyz and id not in (
  SELECT id FROM table WHERE userID = xyz ORDER BY logintime DESC LIMIT 10
 )
```

-- added:  where userID = xyz

Comment: Sorry guys, this doesn't work with MySql. I get the following error:
    This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Following shows a slightly different subquery syntax, but it's for a select - maybe it'll work for a delete:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856397/mysql-subquery-limit

Comment: Since you want the rows *not* in that subquery, you'd have to join on ID <> subquery.ID

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE from table
WHERE id NOT IN(
      SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY userid ORDER BY logintime DESC LIMIT 10)
```