# SQL - getting a specific value from a row and then using that value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of data with a Name, a Grade, and a Point. For example, "John" got the grade B, which has a point value of 3.0.

How can I select entries that are less than a grade of "B"?

So I somehow need to do something like this

```
Value = select Point from MyTable where Grade="B"
```

and then

```
select * from MyTable where Point < value
```

but obviously SQL has to be one statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it use in subquery as below:

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where Point < (select Point 
               from MyTable 
               where Grade="B")
```

but if you subquery returns more than one row try to use aggregate funcion for example `min`

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where Point < (select min(Point)
               from MyTable 
               where Grade="B")
```

or with `LIMIT` and `join`:

```
select * 
from MyTable mt
join (select Point from MyTable 
      where Grade="B"
      order by Point
      LIMIT 1) mt2 on mt.Point < mt2.Point
```

Comment: Won't work. You need to limit the subquery to one only value.

Comment: The aggregate works but is expensive. Just add a `limit 1` to the subquery.

Comment: @Clodoaldo [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856397/mysql-subquery-limit) says you can.

Comment: That is a subquery in a join. In the case here it won't do.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest selects and add a subquery:

```
SELECT realtable.* 
FROM (SELECT Point FROM MyTable WHERE Grade="B" LIMIT 1) subquery, MyTable realtable
WHERE subquery.Point > realtable.Point
```

Comment: this is also very helpful. although I have to give the answer to the other one since it was first and did answer the question. THANKS!!