# how to substitute limit in subquery of mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query and I know that I can't have limit clause in subquery for mysql is there anyway to write this in a correct syntax?

UPDATE:(SCENARIO)I want to maintain deleted visitors 
and when we want to select deleted visitors I should select distinct ips

```
$deletedvisitors = $wpdb->get_var("
       SELECT count(DISTINCT ip)
       FROM $table_name
       WHERE feed=''
       AND spider=''$normallimit AND id IN ( SELECT * FROM ". $table_name . " order by id limit $delneeded)");
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your query? A usage scenario would help to get you a query that does what you need.

Comment: why *can't* you have a limit? also, why is `$normallimit` in the middle of nowhere?

Comment: this is the syntax of a wordpress query I didn't change it it is from statpresscn plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subQuery and join on it according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856397/mysql-subquery-limit)

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT ip)
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM ". $table_name . "
    LIMIT 10
    ) q
JOIN    $table_name
ON      q.id = $table_name.id
```