# Convert MS Access "TOP" to MySQL "LIMIT" in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I am trying to convert an MS Access query to MySQL and the problem is converting MS Access `top` to MySQL `limit` to get the same result. When I change query to `limit` I get the error that this version of MySQL does not support `limit` in subquery.

This is the MS Access query:

```
SELECT  a.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID
FROM tPUBLISHERS 
INNER JOIN (tCONTRIBUTORS AS b 
    INNER JOIN tCLIPS AS a ON b.CONTRIBUTOR_ID = a.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID) 
    ON tPUBLISHERS.PUBLISHER_ID = b.FK_PUBLISHER_ID
WHERE ((a.CLIP_ID) In 
    (select top 5 CLIP_ID 
     from tCLIPS 
     where FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID = a.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID 
         AND SUSPEND = a.SUSPEND)) 
    AND ((a.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID) In (1922,2034,2099))
```

Comment: "When I change query to "limit" I get the error that this version of MySQL does not support "limit" in subquery." - what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Using latest version Mureinik which is MySQL 5.6.14

Comment: I don't have access to such a build, but I tried on MySQL 5.6.6 and 5.5.32 provided by [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85c14/3/0), and I didn't have any problems with a `limit` clause inside a subquery. Can you post your full MySQL query and error?

Comment: SELECT  a.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID

FROM tPUBLISHERS INNER JOIN (tCONTRIBUTORS AS b INNER JOIN tCLIPS AS a ON b.CONTRIBUTOR_ID = a.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID) ON tPUBLISHERS.PUBLISHER_ID = b.FK_PUBLISHER_ID

WHERE ((a.CLIP_ID) In (select CLIP_ID from tCLIPS where FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID = a.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID AND SUSPEND = a.SUSPEND limit 5)) AND ((a.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID) In (1922,2034,2099))

ERROR:
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously answered at:
[MySQL Subquery LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856397/mysql-subquery-limit/2856430#2856430)

basically change the subquery to a Join

Google for more with "mysql limit on subquery"

Comment: worked answer out from here: http://grokbase.com/t/mysql/mysql/0826rjswmn/workaround-limit-in-subquery-not-allowed